# Делегация прав Клиент -> WCF сервис -> MSSQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, wcf

Доброе утро всем!
Не первый день борюсь с проблемой, которая не дает двигаться дальше.
Есть распределенная система, в которой **клиент** находится на машине №1, **wcf сервис** - на машине №2, а **ms sql server** на машине №3.
На стороне клиента используется уровень имперсонализации Delegation:

```
client.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel = 
    System.Security.Principal.TokenImpersonationLevel.Delegation;
```

На стороне wcf сервиса включена имперсонализация (олицетворение) для всех контрактов операций

```
<serviceAuthorization impersonateCallerForAllOperations="true" />
```

и на каждый контракт операции навешан специальный атрибут

```
[OperationBehavior(Impersonation = ImpersonationOption.Allowed)].
```

Таким образом, олицетворение от клиента к сервису проходит нормально, сервис знает от кого пришел запрос, но уже запрос от wcf-сервиса идет от анонимного пользователя, о чем говорит следующая ошибка:

> Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\АНОНИМНЫЙ ВХОД'.

app.config на стороне клиента: http://pastebin.ru/ZgE5NiCH
web.config на стороне сервиса: http://pastebin.ru/vSNP7s4V

Как заставить wcf-сервис обращаться в базу от лица юзера, который вызвал сервис?

Comment: оно? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650591.aspx

Comment: По-идее, должно все работать... Ошибка где-то в деталях. Поскольку для автора этот вопрос вряд ли уже актуален, я считаю, его надо закрыть.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы использовал SQL-аутентификацию и в зависимости от того, кто обратился к сервису, менял бы пользователя в строке подключения.